# ios: NSLocale/Grouping Separator - annoying warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I'm using `NSLocale` quite a lot for Numbers or Currency formatting. For example I use it this way:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
// Config the NSNumberFormatter ...
formatter.groupingSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
```

The compiler always gives me the warning: `Multiple methods named 'objectForKey:' found`

This gets really annoying in larger projects (20+ warnings of this type). The only way I found to get rid of this warning is doing a type cast to `NSDictionary`:

```
formatter.groupingSeparator = [(NSDictionary *)[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
```

This works but I'm not sure if this will lead to problems as `[NSLocale currentLocale]` seems not directly to be an `NSDictionary` (`[[NSLocale currentLocale] class]` returns `__NSCFLocale`).

Is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMD+Click to your `objectForKey` statement. Xcode will find the method at NSDictionary.h.

Now change your code like

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
...
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
formatter.groupingSeparator = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
```

and CMD+Click again to this `objectForKey` statement. Xcode will go to correct place, NSLocale.h.

Or, as you suggested, you can just force-cast NSLocale like

```
formatter.groupingSeparator = [(NSLocale *)[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
```

Comment: Thanks! Stupid compiler ;) Please add also the following alternative to your answer, as it saves 1 line of code: `formatter.groupingSeparator = [(NSLocale *)[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];`